# The command "event:cache" does not exist in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm running unit test using phpunit on laravel 7

After running command `vendor/bin/phpunit` then `tests/bootstrap.php` will be executed.
in that file,we can see `event:cache` inside the array `$commands`

`$commands = ['event:cache']`

The result in the terminal shown as follows

`The command "event:cache" does not exist`

Has the name of the command changed for Laravel 7?

Comment: There's no `tests/bootstrap.php` file included in laravel by default. How and where are you using this file (and what does it contain)?

Comment: I found that file when I maintain the existing project. After creating a new laravel-7 project, indeed, there is no test/bootstrap.php. Thanks for your information :)

Comment: ```tests/bootstrap.php``` looks like this https://gist.github.com/RiansyahTohamba/ffb993f695bed37f0bff3eb73c52523a